# hook_form_alter function to make field visible and required?

Tags: forms, commerce

I'm trying to build a hook_form_alter function to  make field visible and required.

The form is the checkout form at **http://example.com/en/checkout/33**

The targeted field are Customer Profile Billing fields that I added at: **http://example.com/en/admin/commerce/customer-profiles/types/billing/fields**

I tried with:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {   
  if ($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
    $form['field_cif_nif_id'] = array(
         // This #states rule says that the "field_cif_nif_id" fieldset should only
         // be shown if the "field_dispongo_de_" form element is set to "CIF/NIF/ID".
        '#states' => array(
           'visible' => array(
               ':input[name="field_dispongo_de_"]' => array('value' => 'CIF/NIF/ID'),
            ),
        ),
  );

 } 
}
```

it simple doesn't work. No errors.

I need to make the 'field_cif_nif_id' visible and required only if 'field_dispongo_de_' has value 'CIF/NIF/ID'

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that 'field_dispongo_de_' is a '**radio**' type field and 'field_cif_nif_id' is a '**input text**' type.

UPDATED CODE

It is closer but not working yet.

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {   
  if ($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['field_cif_nif_id'] = array(
       '#states' => array(
           'visible' => array(
               ':input[name="field_dispongo_de_"]' => array('value' => 'CIF/NIF/ID'),
            ),
       ),
    );    
 } 
}
```

Comment: Just an aside: as both fields are `<input>` elements there's no point using the `:input` selector, you'll get better performance using `input`. Shouldn't be the cause of the problem though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the selector from `':input[name="field_dispongo_de_"]'` to the id of the field (`#edit-customer-profile-billing-field-dispongo-de-und`) as below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MODULE-NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check if the form is commerce checkout form.
  if ($form_id == 'commerce_checkout_form_checkout') {
    // Verify the field names are as per the form.
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['field_cif_nif_id']['#states'] = array(
      // This #states rule says that the "field_cif_nif_id" fieldset should only
      // be shown if the "field_dispongo_de_" form element is set to "CIF/NIF/ID".
      'visible' => array(
        '#edit-customer-profile-billing-field-dispongo-de-und' => array('value' => t('cif')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working, should I initialy hide the field using css?

Comment: I forgot to mention that 'field_dispongo_de_' is of the 'radio' type

Comment: Try that once but I believe its not required, one think to check is what is the key for option `CIF/NIF/ID` of field field_dispongo_de_ because we need to pass the key of option `CIF/NIF/ID` and not the value in the #states array.

Comment: I'll try with the key

Comment: It doesn't work using the key.

Comment: How are you adding with key? can you just paste that complete line? The only value to be replaced with key is `CIF/NIF/ID` rest everything will be same it is, i.e `array('value' => t('KEY_OF_OPTION')),`

Comment: '#edit-field-dispongo-de-' => array('value' => 1 ),

Comment: Have you verified `#edit-field-dispongo-de` is the id of the field whose value you want to get, I just added it as reference, the actual id may be different from this. Check it in the HTML using firebug or any debugger.

Comment: You were right. It is '$form['customer_profile_billing']['field_cif_nif_id'] = array(' instead of '$form['field_cif_nif_id'] = array('. Please see my updated code at the bottom of the question. It is not working though... I think the problem is the pointer to the '#edit-field-dispongo-de-' field. Can you check pls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17426/discussion-between-ankit-agrawal-and-chefnelone).

Comment: I'm suspicious that you are using the selector `#edit-field-dispongo-de-`, mainly because of the trailing dash. Drupal never outputs fields with trailing dashes. It converts a field name from `$form[my_field_name]` to `<input id="edit-my-field-name">`